# IQ Test - Squares and lines

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

How does it work? What's the logic behind it?
image from: https://international-iq-test.com/

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Look at the pictures in columns: the third picture in a column is the *symmetric difference* of the first two pictures in that column. That is, the third picture has lines exactly where either the first or the second picture has a line, but not both. The answer should be e).